# adding a new role in Jasper to do only rest calls for synchronous report execution

Tags: rest, roles, jasperserver

i want to create a new role in japser and assign that to a user. i want the user to be able to only to rest api calls "jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/reports/" and not able to login to jasper server at all and look at current configurations.

i have tried this i get the 'Access is denied" error. 
I have tried to update the new role in various xml files  like below.. 
This is what i have tried 
1. added a new role 'ROLE_RESTREADONLY' in jasper server
2. added a new user. Gave him this role
3. added this new role in the /rest_v2/reports in various xml files in the WEB-INF folder in below files to the security intercept url

Here is the changes i did . i get access denied error access.deniedAccess is denied when i tried to do rest api to execute the report with user who has only the ROLE_RESTREADONLY role. if i add ROLE_USER it will work

grep -R --include="*.xml" "ROLE_REST" /opt/tomcat/webapps/jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF
/opt/tomcat/webapps/jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF/applicationContext-pro-rest.xml:        ROLE_RESTREADONLY
/opt/tomcat/webapps/jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security-pro-web.xml:        
/opt/tomcat/webapps/jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security-web.xml:                
[root@attcdp01 WEB-INF]#

Comment: Add [some of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you are using so that we can find your error.

Comment: You are a new contributor and welcome, but this not how you ask a question. You should work on your code and put what have you done so far, here. Read the Help Center topics to learn more about what questions you can ask and what type of questions you have to avoid. [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Community will definitely be glad to help you for right questions.

Comment: i have not done any code change in jasper but updated the below 3 xml files in the WEB-INF directory . (applicationContext-pro-rest.xml
applicationContext-security-web.xml
applicationContext-security-pro-web.xml)